# Formula for getting current revision/version

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to get info about the version/revision history of the document itself via e.g. a formula inside the document?

I'm using Google docs for making a config file for an app and i'd like the client to display which version of the file it's using.

In order to do this I'd (preferably) need a cell in the spreadsheet to display some version info of the document (the Google Docs change date & time?) or if this is not possible, calculate some sort of a hash from the whole spreadsheet so That I at least can see if the current client build had the latest version of config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can get a list of revisions from a file id:

```
function listRevisions(fileId) {
  var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId);
  if (revisions.items && revisions.items.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < revisions.items.length; i++) {
      var revision = revisions.items[i];
      var date = new Date(revision.modifiedDate);
      Logger.log('Date: %s, File size (bytes): %s', date.toLocaleString(), revision.fileSize);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No revisions found.');
  }
}
```

from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive#listing_revisions

Please note that you have to use the 'advanced drive API'.

Comment: This is clearly what i need. 
To get the data into my spreadsheet i need this from a cell and make it return the Logger-output of one revision to the cell.

I did that but now I'm getting "error: Login Required (line 3, file "Code")" That's the "Drive.Revisions.list..." line.

Comment: Seems like this function can't be made into a spreadsheet custom function after all (?) since custom functions can't have the permission to access Drive.Revision...
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions#permissions

Comment: What do you mean by a 'custom function'?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions

I'd need the string that's fetched from revision info to appear on my spreadsheet. So I modified your function to return a desired string and typed "=listRevisions("abcd123...")". 

The function works OK when I'm debugging it in Script Editor, and when I run it for the first time it displays a permission dialog. However when I use it in the spreadsheet, the cell shows an error "error: Login Required (line 3, file "Code")" and doesn't prompt for permissions.

Comment: Ah.  I don't know why exactly you need to list revisions as a function called by =, but if you have some flexibility, you could work around this by having one cell that is monitored, and when it changes (using an onedit listener) you could run your script and update a range with a list of revisions.  Or you could export this script as a webapp and use importxml to import the value.  Webapps don't operating under the same restrictions as spreadsheet custom functions.

Comment: Last week i didn't even know about AppScripts so I'm oblivious to all the stuff it can be used for. Custom functions was just the first method i saw for displaying AppScript output in the sheet. I'll look into the other ways you mentioned. 

I also need to be able to save/export the spreadsheet as an ODS file and it seems the cells with custom functions end up as #!NAME or #ERROR in the ODS :P 

I'll mark your answer as THE answer now because it does solve the question in the title and now it should be up to me to do the rest. 
Thanks. :)