# Is there ay formula to display the named version in a cell in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

Is there any formula to display the named version in a cell in the google sheets

I am trying a add a cell in which the value is the named version of the sheet. So that when ever a named version is saved, it is displayed in the cell itself

Comment: Google sheets doesn't NOT have a native formula to display this information. You _might_ (untested) be able to get that info from a `custom function`, but I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: Related question: [How can I set a named version on a Google Sheet programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52651616/1330560)

Comment: **Correction**: a `custom function` is NOT an options [since custom functions can't have the permission to access Drive.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23069859/1330560)